# PHP Trying to get property of non-object in "C:\...."

Tags: php, sql, object

I am trying to query to check if a password matches a username, When I try to create the class file with the validation I get "Trying to get property of non-object" when I use var_dump.

I have a db class that has all the functions to allow the functionality of querying database, They work fine as I can insert to the database.

```
    class Login extends db{

        public function loginValidation($username,$password){

            $password; $username;

            $query = "SELECT username FROM test WHERE password = '".$username."' AND username = '".$password."'";
            $queryExists = $this->query($query);

            if($queryExists->num_rows > 0){
                return true;
            } else{
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
```

Edit -----------

My SQL query seems to be failing but it makes no sense... The values on this database have been set using a registration form made in a PHP site.

Here are the tables -

```
        SELECT * FROM users;
        +----+----------+----------+
        | id | username | pw       |
        +----+----------+----------+
        | 19 | nathan   |  nathan  |
        | 20 | nathank  | password |
        | 21 | shanel   | password |
        | 22 | fsf      |  bdbdf   |
        | 23 | dawn     | password |
        | 24 | dsafsfd  |  sdfasf  |
        | 25 | kent     |  kent    |
        | 26 | kent`    |  kent    |
        +----+----------+----------+
        8 rows in set
```

When I do the following query....

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE pw = 'nathan';
Empty set
```

I receive nothing, It makes no sense because this is a simple SQL query that I am doing and it's failing?

Comment: Your query failed, you failed to check for failure, and tried to use the boolean `false` you received as if it was an object. **NEVER** assume success with DB operations (or operations on  any other "external" resource). Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise. And note that you're almost certainly vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @MarcB Thank you, I will give it a look now :) I usually use prepared SQL statements but I have a little time tonight and wanted to get familiar with sessions so I just put some rough code together, thank you

Comment: check your query  $query = "SELECT username FROM test WHERE password = '".$username."' AND username = '".$password."'"; it should be  $query = "SELECT username FROM test WHERE password = '".$password."' AND username = '".$username."'";

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap I noticed that after looking at it again, For some strange reason I can do this SQL statement SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = 'nathan'; and it returns my username but as soon as I add "AND password = 'password'; it fails :|

Comment: put here your database users tables values

Comment: @AbhijitJagtap I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i think your code should be

```
class Login extends db{

    public function loginValidation($username,$password){

  //testing purpose
        $password="nathan"; $username="nathan";

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE pw = '".$password."' AND username = '".$username."'";
        $queryExists = $this->query($query);

        if($queryExists->num_rows > 0){
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I made a few changes to the names on the database, But... I now know the issue :D The password field is being posted with spaces in the password, A little sneaky mistake which was hard to spot. Appreciate your help